# Autocomplete Web Service in ASP.Net web forms

Tags: asp.net, web-services, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, tokenize

I have a web service for multiple item selection, its working fine but i am getting Undefined data. anyone can tell me solution for it. I am attaching my error screenshot too with this post, please see them below.

**Web Service JSON Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            SearchText();
        });
function SearchText() {
            $("[id*=ctl00_ContentMain_TextBoxSkills]").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: '<%=ResolveUrl("WebServiceSkills.asmx/GetAutoCompleteData")%>',
                        data: "{'skill':'" + extractLast(request.term) + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response(data.d);
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert("No Result Found");
                        }
                    });
                },
                focus: function () {
                    // prevent value inserted on focus
                    return false;
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    var terms = split(this.value);
                    // remove the current input
                    terms.pop();
                    // add the selected item
                    terms.push(ui.item.value);
                    // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                    terms.push("");
                    this.value = terms.join(", ");
                    return false;
                }
            });
            $("#ctl00_ContentMain_TextBoxSkills").bind("keydown", function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                        $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            })
            function split(val) {
                return val.split(/,\s*/);
            }
            function extractLast(term) {
                return split(term).pop();
            }
        }
    </script>
```

**Web Service:**

```
[WebMethod]

    public List<UserRegistration> GetAutoCompleteData(string skill)
    {
        List<UserRegistration> list = new List<UserRegistration>();
        UserRegistrationHelper userRegistrationHelper = new UserRegistrationHelper();

        using (DataTable dataTable = userRegistrationHelper.GetSkillsList(skill))
        {

            if (CommonFunctions.ValidateDataTable(dataTable))
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
                {
                    var SkillsList = new UserRegistration
                    {
                        SkillId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["SkillId"].ToString()),
                        Skills=dr["SkillName"].ToString()
                    };
                    list.Add(SkillsList);
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Screenshot here: [image: Error image]

Answer (score 0):

I got answer for it:

**1: Change SQL Query:**

```
select concat('[', STUFF  
            (  
                (  
                    SELECT top 15 '","'+ CAST(skillname AS VARCHAR(MAX))  
                    from DNH_Master_Skills where SkillName LIKE '%' + @SkillName + '%'
                    FOR XMl PATH('')  
                ),1,2,''  
            ),'"]')
```

**2: Change JSON Code:**

```
From: response(data.d); TO: response(Array.parse(data.d));
```

Now its working feeling happy.